# How did Thanos not realise this had happened at the end of Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* right at the end,

> Iron Man steals all the Infinity Stones right from Thanos.

But whenever

> someone gets the stones,

it's this huge deal with electricity, etc. So,

> why didn't Thanos notice the Infinity Stones were gone?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Iron Man uses his nanotech to steal the stones, and if you watch carefully when Tony Stark's hand comes around to reveal he has the stones, the nanotech in his suit is still forming the gauntlet itself and moving the stones into the right positions.

Once they are located in the correct spots, the electricity starts to spark as you expected and Tony wastes no time in getting the snap done.

Thanos didn't notice the stones being taken off the existing nanotech gauntlet because Tony only grabbed his hand for a second or so and didn't get the gauntlet off him - it didn't occur to him that there was any way in which the stones could be removed from the gauntlet in those few seconds.

Comment: I see, thank you, do you happen to know what this nanotech is meant to do? That Thanos wouldn't feel the stones, which seem like a weird power source, missing?

Comment: The nanotech is what makes up Tony's armour in both Infinity War and Endgame and it responds to Tony's thoughts, which is why it can form whatever shapes he desires, and why he can command it to transfer the stones from Thanos's gauntlet to his own suit.

Comment: Also remember that the gauntlet that Thanos is wearing is in fact _also_ Stark technology.  It's not unreasonable to think that Stark might have put in an "eject all the stones" backdoor command into it.  They could have tried to make that explicit in the movie, but it would have been a huge telegraph of the climatic moment.

Comment: Certainly if I knew I was about to attach the infinity stones to my hand, I'd like the option to eject them as soon as I don't need them! Those things caused real damage to Thanos and Hulk, being able to emergency-eject the stones might be the difference between getting away with a torn up arm vs a horrible death.

Comment: @Jherico: I'd argue that there isn't actually any conscious design feature for "EJECT ALL THE STONES NOW". We see that Stark makes it a priority to grab the "Startlet". While Stark definitely doesn't want Thanos to snap his fingers, it's entirely reasonable that Stark needed that to interface directly with the nanites to order them to change (and in this case, remove the stones and pass them to Stark's suit). Stark's nanosuits seem pretty responsive to his desires, as they transform into their different shapes pretty quickly in the heat of combat.

Answer (score 96):

### This Thanos had never used the stones before, and didn't know what to expect

Dave's answer covers why Thanos didn't notice *Tony* sparking.  But it doesn't explain why he missed the lack of pain on his own hand.

But this Thanos is from 2014, and had never seen the fully complete Gauntlet before.  He didn't know to expect excruciating pain upon activating it.

Also, Tony's Gauntlet works differently from the original Infinity Gauntlet.  If you [watch Thanos add the last stone](https://youtu.be/-HY9F9uUuJ8?t=317) in Infinity War, the Gauntlet surges in power, but then the surge dies away.  Even if Thanos was familiar with the specs of the original Gauntlet, he would expect the power surge from the Gauntlet to stop, and he wouldn't know that Tony's weaker Gauntlet never stops sparking and surging.  So when the pain vanished while he was fighting with Tony, it didn't occur to him that something was wrong.

Comment: Heck, that Thanos didn't even know about the pain inherent in attaching even *one* stone to the gauntlet, because he didn't have any of the stones yet...

Comment: @Shadur Didn't Thanos already had mind stone before?

Comment: Not at the point where they snatched the stones, apparently.

Comment: @Shadur When they snatched power stone, Thanos from that time already had mind stone in his possession (before it was lost to earth during battle of New York)

Answer (score 8):

I know I'm too late for this question, but it didn't occur to me until now, why Thanos could have never **suspected** Tony stealing the Infinity stones from him; it's because of his arrogance in the Final battle. He himself says that to Nebula soon after arriving to the Future.

> Nebula: "They didn't suspect a thing"
>
> Thanos: "The arrogant never do"

Obviously Thanos became arrogant from the time he saw so many Avengers join Captain for the battle; he rains fire on his own troops. He's devastated to see Cpt. Marvel destroy his ship with ease, so all this arrogance made him **not** suspect Tony taking away the Infinity stones from him.

Comment: +1 and this difference is something they played really well I think. Infinity War Thanos had been on a journey, lost friends, faced failure and betrayal, made painful sacrifices. He was mature, wise, humble, and respected his enemies' strengths. Endgame Thanos was arrogant and complacent like a spoilt kid who had just been given everything he wanted on a silver platter - and this time it was the heroes who were prepared and knew what kind of challenge to expect.

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8 nice. you might answer this! https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100556/why-was-endgame-thanos-so-different-than-infinity-war-thanos